# Understanding when and why to use different Android threads

Tags: android

Hopefully someone can explain this to me or point me to a resource I can read to learn more. I am building an app that uses a `ListView` and a *custom list adapter* that I modeled off one of the many tutorials available online such as this one:

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

It worked fine. However, every example of how to do this runs the process of building the list of objects to be displayed and collecting the required data on separate threads.

I want to know why/couldn't you just put everything into `onCreate`? I can't see a reason why you would need separate threads to make this happen. Is there some general form/standard for when/what must me run on certain threads?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) on this are very good, as with most things.

The upshot is: the UI should always be responsive. So `if you have some operation that will take enough time that the user will notice, you might want to consider not running it in the UI thread`. Some common examples are `network IO` and `database accesses`. It's something of a case-by-case basis though, so you have to make the call for yourself a bit.

Comment: Ok so the idea is to delegate tasks that may take more time to other threads so that the main thread isn't waiting for information from elsewhere while it could be running something else. So while you could run everything from onCreate it just probably isn't the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Well it depends on how you define "efficient". The best practice suggests generally that if you have something that will take a "noticeable" amount of time, then you should move it out of the UI thread, and therefore out of onCreate. It's also somewhat contingent on whether or not you need the results to display the UI, etc. But yes, your comment is correct in general I would say.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if building the list of objects is not a relatively short process, doing it in onCreate() would be blocking/slowing the main thread.  If you use a separate thread, it will allow the android os to load all of the UI elements while you are waiting for the list to be populated.  Then when the list of objects is ready, you can instantly populate the already initialized UI, as opposed to waiting to initialize the UI until after the list of objects is built.  It ensures that your application will always be responsive for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Because you only have 0.5 sec to execute onCreate — after which the dreaded ADN (application not responding) error message is displayed. So unless your list view is super simple you won't make it it in time. And even if your list view is super simple it is better to learn it the proper way.

BTW: I don't even use threads, I use one or more Services to do all the work. Even more difficult to implement but more robust and responsive as well.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't do things in onCreate or on the UI thread is for responsiveness. If your app takes too long to process, the user gets shown an App Not Responding dialog.

Answer (score 0):

my teacher once said: every software can be written in a single (big) for loop.

And if you think: it can be... maybe at NDK level.

Some SDK developers wanted to make the software developers tasks easier and that's, why exists the SDK's and frameworks.

Unless you don't need anything from multitasking you should use single threading.

Sometimes there are time limitations, sometimes UI/background/networking limitations and need to do stuff in diff threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you see source code of Asyntask and Handler, you will see their code purely in Java. (of course, there some exceptions, but that is not an important point).

Why does it mean ? It means no magic in Asyntask or Handler. They just make your job easier as a developer.

For example: If ProgramA calls methodA(), methodA() would run in a different thread with ProgramA.You can easily test by:

`Thread t = Thread.currentThread();

 int id = t.getId();`

And why you should use new thread ? You can google for it. Many many reasons.

So, what is the difference ?

AsyncTask and Handler are written in Java (internally use a Thread), so everything you can do with Handler or AsyncTask, you can achieve using a Thread too.

What Handler and AsyncTask really help you with?

The most obvious reason is communication between caller thread and worker thread. (Caller Thread: A thread which calls the Worker Thread to perform some task.A Caller Thread may not be the UI Thread always). And, of course, you can communicate between two thread by other ways, but there are many disadvantages, for eg: Main thread isn't thread-safe (in most of time), in other words, DANGEROUS.

That is why you should use Handler and AsyncTask. They do most of the work for you, you just need to know what methods to override.

Difference Handler and AsyncTask: Use AsyncTask when Caller thread is a UI Thread. This is what android document says:

`AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers`

I want to emphasize on two points:

1) Easy use of the UI thread (so, use when caller thread is UI Thread).

2) No need to manipulate handlers. (means: You can use Handler instead of AsyncTask, but AsyncTask is an easier option).

There are many things in this post I haven't said yet, for example: what is UI Thread, of why it easier. You must know some method behind each kind and use it, you will completely understand why..

@: when you read Android document, you will see:

`Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue`

They may seem strange at first.Just understand that, each thread has each message queue. (like a To do List), and thread will take each message and do it until message queue emty. (Ah, maybe like you finish your work and go to bed). So, when Handler communicates, it just gives a message to caller thread and it will wait to process. (sophiscate ? but you just know that, Handler can communicate with caller thread in safe-way)